# OpenDaylight Dlux unable to see hosts

Tags: mininet, opendaylight

I run the mininet with:

`sudo mn --topo single,3 --controller remote,ip=... port=6653 --switch ovsk, protocols=OpenFlow13`

Then I run the controller OpenDaylight(Helium,Karaf). I installed features:
         odl-openflowplugin-all , odl-dlux-core, odl-restconf, odl-mdsal-apidocs, odl-openflowplugin-flow-services-ui, odl-openflowplugin-flow-services-rest

Then I add the flow from the computer which mininet runs, manually by

```
sudo ovs-ofctl -O OpenFlow13 add-flow "s1" in_port=1,actions=output:2
sudo ovs-ofctl -O OpenFlow13 add-flow "s1" in_port=2, actions=output:1
```

Then I use "pingall" command at mininet promt. As it is expected h1 and h2 can ping each other while they couldn't ping h3.

Finally, I tried to check the flow from Dlux GUI, however what I saw was the only switch. Then I tried to look at flows, and again couldn't see anything.

What is the problem? If anyone can helps I would be gratefull

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

run the `ping-all` command in `mininet`. It shows whether pings are successful or not. If pings are successful then you will be able to see hosts also.

Answer (score 0):

Stop the running controller and check for the port 6633 by running the command,

ps -eaf | grep ":6633"

If any of the service is running on this port, kill them by the command

sudo kill -9 pid #pid: Process ID of the running service

then, try to install these features:

opendaylight-user@root>feature:install odl-l2switch-switch odl-restconf odl-mdsal-apidocs

Now, start the mininet and check for connectivity between controller and mininet.

Originally Answered by [bhavesh07](https://ask.opendaylight.org/users/337/bhavesh07/) in the opendaylight [forum](https://ask.opendaylight.org/question/647/unable-to-connect-opendaylight-from-mininet/)